# Single Controller for HTML and JSON results

Tags: php, model-view-controller

While writing a controller, are there any pitfalls in having a single action respond to multiple response formats? AFAIK, Rails does this with 'respond_to' but couldn't find something similar in PHP. Frameworks that provide facility to create 'REST' controller (e.g. Laravel) do so with focus only on the REST API, thereby separating out the 'UI' controller. So, wondering if this is not advisable.

Also, what are the points to be considered while writing such a controller action (if it's not a bad practice)? Couple of things that come to my mind is caching and different output fields for different formats. Anything else that I should consider?

Comment: As far as I can tell presenting HTML and JSON have different goals. HTML is mostly page markup and JSON mostly represents a objects state. I don't see how you can handle them the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers in MVC are  responsible for altering state of model layer and in very rare cases - for altering current view state. Of course, if you are using Rails or Laravel as example, you do not have MVC.

Format of the response should be governed by views.

As for POST/GET/PUT/DELETE - in my experience it is better to have the request methods as a prefix in controllers actions (like `getArticle( $request )`, `putArticle( $request )`, etc.), because that way you avoid having actions with multiple brunching `if` statements.

Comment: Great! This makes sense. Just to confirm, as long as the view layer handles response formats, it's fine to (or even, it's better to) have a single controller to manage the model layer, and send results to view layer to deal with formatting. Am I right?

Comment: No, single controller wont do. In context of RESTful application you probably will have a controller per resource.

Comment: Sure, I mean single controller from the perspective of coordinating operations of that particular resource and then leaving it to view layer to respond to different formats, as opposed to having multiple controllers for different response formats. I hope we're in agreement that when it comes to response format, the number of controllers shouldn't depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know CakePHP does exactly what Rails does. Just add `Router::parseExtensions('json')` to your routes file and enable the `RequestHandlerComponent` in your controllers. [1](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)

You could do it with virtually every framework out there by, for instance, reading the Accept header and respond accordingly.

Comment: My question is about if there are any pitfalls; not if it's doable. When I didn't see frameworks doing it, I was wondering if it's proper or a bad practice. (Now that I know from you that CakePHP does it, I still am unsure if there are any pitfalls in that or what are the things to be considered while doing so.)

Comment: I think it works when you are building a very simple CRUD app. Your controller actions return a resource, so if you are only passing eg. users to your html view it makes sense to let that same action respond with json or xml IMO. When passing multiple variables to a html view I would go with a seperate REST api.